# Cross-site publishing with star rating

Tags: 2013, social, rating, cross-site-publishing

We are setting up a cross-site publishing solution. Got that working fairly well following [this tutorial](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/02/14/how-to-set-up-a-product-centric-web-site-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx). But we would like our users to be able to rate the individual items on the publishing side (the side that the user's will see.) The tutorial that we have been following clearly shows ratings, so it is something that Microsoft is presenting as doable.

I've found several questions about this on the web, but nobody seems to have shared an answer.

Any tips or ideas for making this work?